# How does one successfully download AND import pygame?

Tags: python, macos, import, pygame

***the problem***:

as part of my studies, i have tried to download *PyGame* for my own independent project. I've currently downloaded **1.9.6**, as well as currently owning *IDLE* version **3.8**. i have imported it many times:

folder.
[on one occasion , i placed it in its own separate folder with the coding file  in another internal folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szrs3.png)

[when importing it into a new python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkcbT.png), the result was that there was "no module named Pygame", even though it was in a file containing the recent edition (this method was used successfully to download Tkinter).

I also tried making a python script outside the contained folder  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEXk8.png)

this,too had the same result.

Any idea what exactly to do?

***any more important information***

The computer type is a **MAC** 10.13.6 and the IDE is **IDLE**. As previously mentioned, the downloaded version is version 1.9.6 and i have not a clue what how many bits my computer manages. Apologies that this is probably one of MILLIONS of the exact same question answered.I've tried at least 2 of these solutions.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure that you have `pip` installed. Type `pip` in your cmd (command prompt) and if you get no errors you are fine. If you have errors [follow this link](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-pip-for-python/) to get it. If you are stuck on that link - basically all you need to do is uninstall python and then when you are installing it again tick the box that says:

> Add Python 3.5 to PATH

[image: Where the box is]

Now just finish installing python.

Next you need to install pygame with `pip install pygame` in your cmd - run it as administrator just to be safe. If you receive errors try updating pip with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Now create and save a new python file. Import pygame in that file by using the code `import pygame`. The output should be:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

[image: import pygame output]

Now you are free to code in pygame! I hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for such a descriptive solution. I'm a bit stuck at downloading PIP (which is apparently "not found"), i'll try downloading it, but it seemingly requires a password when attempting to install it.I have never used command line before, but, actually, it could come in handy.

Comment: i have edited on a simple method for installing pip @C4d1ngFl3dg3L1ng . I hope that I have been helpful